# Href to another div id on submit in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which contains a submit button. When I click this submit button I want to go to another div with id home. This is what I am doing now (which is not working):

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" href="#home" name="action" value="Redirect"/>
```

For example if I had:

```
 <div id="home"><ul><li>Hello World</li></ul></div>
 <input type="submit" class="submit" href="#home" name="action" value="Redirect"/>
```

This won't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide all of the HTML?

Comment: None of the suggestions below have worked. They all just redirect to the previous screen.

Comment: You need to provide a better example of the HTML you're working with. As I noted in my answer, href is not a valid attribute for an input element. You also have the input type as submit but I see no indication that it is in a form. What you're trying to achieve is not difficult, but getting a working solution for you is when we lack all or most of the information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the action of the form be '#home'. Then add a named anchor above the home div.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a name="home"></a>
        <div style="height:1500px;">

        </div>
        <form action="#home">
            <input type="submit" value="Home">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but events would require the user has javascript on.

Answer (score 0):

href is not a valid attribute for an input element. Try this:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="location.href = '#home'" name="action" value="Redirect"/>
```

If this is inside of a form, it will submit the form unless you have something preventing that from happening.

Comment: This will not intercept a submit via keyboard.

Comment: Actually it will if they're pressing space or enter on the button: http://jsfiddle.net/hWyvX/ As for submitting in a textbox, we have limited info from the poster.

Answer (score 0):

just u mention the redirect page in one function.... then that function name calling via onclcik="function_name";

```
for eg:

function_name
{
some code .......
location.href = 'home.html';
}
<input type="button" onclick="function_name">
your code..........
```